# Какой смысл в записи queueSize | 0 ? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, c#

Я переписываю [код](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/dbb02448b0f93e4c82c3) javascript на C#. И не могу понять какой смысл записи `queueSize | 0` в выражении:

```
  var i = Math.random() * queueSize | 0,
      s = queue[i],
      j = 0;
```

| - [это Присваиванием с побитовым OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Bitwise_OR_assignment)

Побитовый оператор присваивания OR использует двоичное (бинарное) представление обоих операндов, выполняет побитовое ИЛИ для них и присваивает результат переменной.

```
Оператор: x |= y 
Значение:  x  = x | y

var bar = 5;
bar |= 2; // 7
// 5: 00000000000000000000000000000101
// 2: 00000000000000000000000000000010
// -----------------------------------
// 7: 00000000000000000000000000000111
```

тут же какое бы не было значение queueSize , выражение `queueSize | 0` будет всегда значение queueSize.
В коде это просто лишнее действие или имеет какой то смысл такое выражение `queueSize | 0` ?
Не могу понять. javascript изучал давно.

Comment: Сам в JS не "секу", но думаю, что язык не настолько "сломан" (имеется ввиду как стандарт (если так что-то можно сломать...), так и интерпретатор), чтобы ничего не дающая операция что-то давала. Скорее всего это простая ошибка в коде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Math.random() возвращает число между 0 и 1, которое дальше в коде используется как индекс, который должен быть целым числом. Побитовый `|` с нулем ничего не делает, но отбрасывает дробную часть. Фактически, это то же самое, что и `Math.trunc(n)` или `parseInt(n)`

```js
let queueSize = 10;
let rand = Math.random();

console.log( rand * queueSize );
console.log( rand * queueSize | 0 );

// Побочка: всё, что NaN - превращает в ноль
console.log( undefined | 0 );
console.log( NaN | 0 );
console.log( "moo" | 0 );
```

Его в первую очередь используют для получения целого числа. Если нужно избавиться только от NaN, обычно используют логическое ИЛИ `Math.random() * queueSize || 0;`

Comment: а еще он обрезает операнды до 32 бит

Answer (score 0):

Смысл простой что не былo undefined в итоге. Чтоб индекс был адекватным,а не NaN или undefined

```
console.log(undefined | 0) или console.log(undefined) 
console.log(NaN | 0) или console.log(NaN)
```

Comment: Тут ещё используется факт что битовые операции округляют операнды до целого числа